# Irregular grid render in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to understand how can I render in React a grid that looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxuAR.png)

Comment: That's 4 boxes in 2 columns where the second column has a bit of top margin.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Like so, for example.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  padding: .5em;
}

.col:nth-child(2n) {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.box {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  padding: .5em;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```